# Potential leak of an object allocated in iphone

Tags: iphone

In my application I m using following code below:-

```
NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)], nil];
    [toolbarItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];
```

For that it shows Potential leak of an object .

Comment: try splitting up such lines and you will see the issue easier. NSArray adds a retain count to each object it adds and then releases them when you release the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's a potential leak because you created a `UIBarButtonItem` that you owned (since you invoked `alloc`), but lost the reference to it by directly putting it into the array.  As such, the analyzer is reporting that you leaked it.

Besides that, the code is *terrible*.  I can't think of *any* valid situation where you'd ever want to do `[anArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];`

Comment: No need to call it terrible. Simply describe any pitfalls with the presented strategy or suggest an improved alternative.

Comment: I can think of many valid situations where [anArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)]; comes in very handy. Perhaps it's just a different style of coding then.

Comment: You may want to slap the guy who wrote NSViewController then, Dave

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array using arrayWith... the object is autorelease so you don't need to release the object.  you do release when you create objects with the [[alloc] init] style